# Responsive Parallel Coordinates chart in D3js

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design, parallel-coordinates

I have made a parallel coordinates chart, now I want to make it responsive.
For the purpose of testing responsiveness, I thought to first make [this example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021) responsive.

The problem I am facing is that if I put the "svg" directly inside "body" tag, it works perfectly. But when I place the "svg" inside some divs, the chart gets cropped when the window is resized. Also, the height of the svg is mentioned as 70%, if I make it 80% then the chart gets cropped without any resize. I know there is another option which is to use viewBox and preserveAspectRatio, but I used this approach as it was easy to understand, for me or any other person reading my code. Here is the approach:

```
 d3.csv("data.csv",function(data){
  ....
 function resize(){
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#mychart").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = parseInt(d3.select("#mychart").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      x.rangePoints([0, width], 1);

      svg.select("#mychart")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
            return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
                .range([height, 0]));
          }));

      svg.selectAll(".line").attr("d", path);

      g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; });

      g.selectAll(".axis")
          .each(function(d) {d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
        .append("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("y", -9)
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
  }
  d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
  resize();
});
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tjILhP9yyCrsP4uONdsj?p=preview) is the plunker link for the full code. Can anybody please point out whats wrong with the code?

Comment: The chart doesn't get cropped for me when resizing in the plunker you linked. I am using Firefox 44.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning before but the chart gets cropped on resize. Also, the height of svg is mentioned as 70%, if I increase it to 80%, the chart gets cropped without any resize.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about understanding **CSS**.

Specifically, you can give your `<svg>` element a `height` of `100%`, and then set the size of the containing element.

See [my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vPgFSRXGzxLitZPaDZvW?p=preview).

Here, the `<svg>` always has a `height` of `100%`, and the `<div>` containing the `<svg>` has a percentage `height`, which is in turn relative to the `.container-fluid` container, which has an absolute height (in [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)).

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622097/502331):

> If you want to make the div height a percentage of the viewport height, every ancestor of the div, including  and , have to have height: 100%, so there is a chain of explicit percentage heights down to the div.
>
> Alternatively, all modern browsers and IE>=9 support new CSS units relative to viewport height (vh) and viewport width (vw):

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573878/502331):

> To cause your SVG to fill an HTML element, put the CSS attribute `position:relative` (or `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` if appropriate) on your wrapper, and then [...] set the CSS attribute `position:absolute` on your `<svg>` element to cause it to sit inside and fill your div. (If necessary, also apply `left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%`.)

You can (as I did) use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) to set the height of the containing `div`.

Alternatively, you could try using the [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property to position your `.row` elements.

---

Also, your `resize()` function can be greatly simplified. It needs to do three things:

1. Update the **range** of your **scales**
2. Update any **attributes** that use those scales
3. Call your **axis** function

```js
  function resize() {
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#mychart").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#mychart").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    x.rangePoints([0, width], 1);

    d3.values(y).forEach(function(scale) {
      scale.range([height, 0])
    })

    svg.selectAll(".line").attr("d", path);

    g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";
      });

    g.selectAll(".axis").call(axis.scale(y[d]))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went through your example. Can you explain me how giving height as "vh" is useful? When I make the window smaller, the chart does gets chopped with height as 70vh. If I change it to 50vh, it gets chopped if I further reduce the window size. So, is it like we have to set a viewport height by trial & error? And also, what if I want a minimum height & width for the svg?